# How to provide custom Expression or Predicate with JPA QueryBuilder

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa, full-text-search, eclipselink

I am using JPA2 (EclipseLink implementation) with Spring Data and using Specification pattern to provide filter specification.

How can I introduce custom Expression or Predicate that will map to custom SQL operator? I have particularly in mind using PostgreSQL FTS extension and add conditions like this:

```
SELECT ... WHERE ... AND column @@ 'ts query'
```

to my Specification instance.

Comment: JPQL supports generalised SQL functions using "FUNCTION", maybe that

Comment: @Neil Stockton: I know that, but is it possible to mix JPQL with Specification object? If yes - that would be OK...

Comment: Since "Specification object" (no idea what that is) is not part of JPA then the answer is clearly no, see the JPA spec

Comment: "Specification" object is part of Spring Data and is used to build criteria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few ways to do that:

1. If switching to Hibernate is an option, there is a way to do that using Hibernate infrastructure:

```
For HQL in Hibernate
http://java-talks.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/use-postgresql-full-text-search-with-hql.html

And for integrating Hibernate implementation with JPQL
http://metabroadcast.com/blog/hibernate-and-postgres-fts

Basically, what you need to do is 

-  Override your PostgreSQL Dialect
-  Register functions with appropriate interpreters
-  Call functions, when you need to use FTS
```

2. If you can't go with Hibernate, you still can do it, by basically using the same approach, as described above, but with EclipseLink specifics

Here is a link of how you can do it, using EclipseLink https://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_EclipseLink_Expressions_%28ELUG%29

Basically you'll need to do the same staff, but EclipseLink style

Based on Documentation, it can look something like this:

```
public class MyDatabasePlatform extends DatabasePlatform {

   final private int FTS_ID = Interger.MAX_VALUE;
        
   protected void initializePlatformOperators() {
      super.initializePlatformOperators();
      // Create user-defined function

      ExpressionOperator fts = new ExpressionOperator();
      fts.setSelector(FTS_ID);
      List args = new ArrayList();
      args.addElement(" @@ to_tsquery(");
      args.addElement(")");
      fts.printAs(args);
      fts.bePrefix();
      fts.setNodeClass(FunctionExpression.class);

      // Make it available to this platform only
      ExpressionOperator.registerOperator(FTS_ID, "fts");
      addOperator(fts);
   }

}
```

Although I'm not sure about that code, you'll need to test this.

Comment: I tried to follow 2) suggestion and I am able to prepare criteria but only using eclipselink native classes... is there a way I could use this using:
javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder, javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery, javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate, etc?

Comment: I managed to work it out. Extending DatabasePlatfor is still handy because you can use new operator in jpql like: SELECT t FROM entity t WHERE OPERATOR('fts', COLUMN('fts_column_in_table', t), 'fts & query & string'); but to prepare JPA criteria you need to do something different: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29509261/eclipselink-jpa-criteria-reference-unmapped-column

Comment: There is a description, of how to add it to CriteriaBuilder in the hibernate article.